# incorrect geom_polygon

Tags: r, ggmap

I have a dataset:

```
  id_hex   mean   dif      long      lat  group
1      0   0.08  0.01 -97.75515 30.26387    0.1
2      0   0.08  0.01 -97.75520 30.26377    0.1
3      0   0.08  0.01 -97.75628 30.26193    0.1
4      0   0.08  0.01 -97.75676 30.26112    0.1
5      0   0.08  0.01 -97.75707 30.26061    0.1
6      0   0.08  0.01 -97.75780 30.25939    0.1
```

and so on..

I have a list with my SpatialPolygons and try to plot data like that:

```
ggmap(mymap) + geom_polygon(data = df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = dif), alpha = 0.5) +
      geom_path(data = my_poligons, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), size = 0.5)
```

If i use only geom_path I get the outlines of the districts, but if I close these outlines through geom_polygon, I get the painted areas completely, i.e. All the empty skeletons inside the areas are covered in color, how to fix it?

[image: Its a districts]

[image]

The districts are not correctly painted in comparison with this http://www.austintexas.gov/page/city-council-district-map

UPDATE: I found out that you do not need to use the hole column from the parsed SpatialPoligon, how i can do it?

Comment: Could be nice to have an image. Not sure if I have understood correctly but you have fixed the color of each polygon with `fill = dif`so yeah it's normal.

Comment: @MbrMbr check it

Comment: so you wonder why you have sometimes some blocks in color inside in an area who is already colored ?

Comment: @MbrMbr I'm not surprised, I understand why they are there, I do not know how to remove them.

Comment: Hm ok what you can check is to verify that those small areas are defined in the same group as the big area they are in. I don't know if it's clear but let's say a big area has `1.1` as value of `group`, try to check it there are values like `1.2`, `1.3`etc.

Comment: @MbrMbrI have already checked this, the values are identical for each group

Comment: Well maybe there is a way to not display overlapping polygons with the arg `position`. You can go to : https://gis.stackexchange.com/, they can help you as well

Comment: @MbrMbr i need fill only a false holes from dataset